# Python - Pandas — How to check which column a DataFrame is grouped by?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a function that outputs a grouped DataFrame. I now want to find out by which column this DataFrame was grouped. How can I do this?

EDIT:

Here's some code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'A' : [0, 1, 2],
                'B' : [1, 6, 5],
                'C' : [2, 5, 4]
                 } )
grp = df.groupby('A')
```

The question is how to determine that grp is grouped by A.

---

Below, john-galt gives an extremely helpful answer. <s>However, I've found one case where it's not immediately obviously how to apply his solution: using a custom grouping function.</s>

EDIT 2: Never mind, that case was not what I thought it was. My question has been answered.

Comment: Code? Example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by a "grouped DataFrame" ?

Comment: Code added, apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `grp.grouper.names`

Like, for the datframe

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  1  6  5
```

`grp` is the grouped object

```
In [48]: grp = df.groupby('A')
```

Use `grouper.names` to get the column names.

```
In [49]: grp.grouper.names
Out[49]: ['A']
```

---

Also, `grp.grouper` object has lot of other useful metadata, you may find it useful

```
In [50]: grp.grouper.
grp.grouper.agg_series       grp.grouper.group_info       grp.grouper.names
grp.grouper.aggregate        grp.grouper.group_keys       grp.grouper.ngroups
grp.grouper.apply            grp.grouper.groupings        grp.grouper.nkeys
grp.grouper.axis             grp.grouper.groups           grp.grouper.result_index
grp.grouper.compressed       grp.grouper.indices          grp.grouper.shape
grp.grouper.get_group_levels grp.grouper.labels           grp.grouper.size
grp.grouper.get_iterator     grp.grouper.levels           grp.grouper.sort
```